# Update all occurence of a specific column in entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server, updates

I have Asset table and **assetid**(column) in many table use

I want to update all occurences of tables in all occurences of inserts in database

**assetid**(column) **WHERE** value has 878 to 1 **FROM** all tables in database

I know normal update

```
update AdminInterests set assetid = 1 where 878
```

I just want to how to apply update through entire database in all tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query to create all the needed `UPDATE` statements.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME + ' SET assetid  = 1 where asssetid = 878;'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
AND c.COLUMN_NAME ='assetid'
```

And then you can execute those `UPDATE` statements.

[***Sample Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33e0d827fba5bf62b2fdee90dbc2cc42)

Comment: Wow thanks query also show's how many table uses assetid column total 13. It seems I have to execute my self

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, you have to execute the update statements manually. You can create a dynamic SQL if you want that to be executed automatically @Baganaakh

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is that you could read database meta data tables and build a dynamic query to find all the columns/attributes you’d like to update and then run an update against them. It’s quite a lot of work to do that but does provide a solution. It’s also a programmatic solution rather than one that you can do with a query.